# t-test doesn't work in function - variable lengths differ

Tags: r

Bit of a R novice here, so it might be a very simple problem.

I've got a dataset with GENDER (being a binary variable) and a whole lot of numerical variables. I wanted to write a simple function that checks for equality of variance and then performs the appropriate t-test.

So my first attempt was this:

```
genderttest<-function(x){                                             # x = outcome variable

  attach(Dataset)
  on.exit(detach(Dataset))  

  VARIANCE<-var.test(Dataset[GENDER=="Male",x], Dataset[GENDER=="Female",x])

  if(VARIANCE$p.value<0.05){
    t.test(x~GENDER)
  }else{
    t.test(x~GENDER, var.equal=TRUE)
  }
}
```

This works well outside of a function (replacing the x, of course), but gave me an error here because variable lengths differ.

So I thought it might be handling the NA cases strangely and I should clean up the dataset first and then perform the tests:

```
genderttest<-function(x){                                               # x = outcome variable
  Dataset2v<-subset(Dataset,select=c("GENDER",x))
  Dataset_complete<-na.omit(Dataset2v)

  attach(Dataset_complete)
  on.exit(detach(Dataset_complete))  

  VARIANCE<-var.test(Dataset_complete[GENDER=="Male",x], Dataset_complete[GENDER=="Female",x])

  if(VARIANCE$p.value<0.05){
    t.test(x~GENDER)
  }else{
    t.test(x~GENDER, var.equal=TRUE)
  }
}
```

But this gives me the same error.

I'd appreciate if anyone could point out my (probably stupid) mistake.

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example so we can search the error ?

Comment: By reproducible, you mean an example that creates the dataset in question in the beginning?

Comment: Either that dataset or another more simple but similar that we can use instead

Comment: Okay, I was too slow in making a reproducible example. JVL already found the solution. But thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that when you call `t.test(x~GENDER)`, it's evaluating the variable `x` within the scope of `Dataset` rather than the scope of your function. So it's trying to compare values of `x` between the two genders, and is confused because `Dataset` doesn't have a variable called `x` in it.

A solution that should work is to call:

```
do.call('t.test', args=list(formula=as.formula(paste0(x,'~GENDER')), data=Dataset))

do.call('t.test', args=list(formula=as.formula(paste0(x,'~GENDER')), var.equal=T, data=Dataset))
```

which will call `t.test()` and pass the value of `x` as part of the formula argument rather than the character x (i.e `score ~ GENDER` instead of `x ~ GENDER`).

The reason for the particular error you saw is that `Dataset$GENDER` has length equal to the number of rows in `Dataset`, while `Dataset$x` has length = 0.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I thought I would get an "object not found" error if it was treating x the way you described, but your solution worked so that must have been the problem. Thanks again!